# DAL Design and Guidance

Tags: c#, database, data-access-layer

I need some guidance on creating a DAL. I have tried to find some good resources but have not come across anything specific to my needs.

I have a slightly complex database layout with a few one-to-many relationships and a single many-to-many. Most of the articles I have seen online reference entity framework to help with the ORM but unfortunately I cannot use this as I cannot use reflection/emit

Currently, I have one class exactly representing each table in my database. I then have a generic repository so I can manipulate these classes. On top of that, I have a further layer (service layer??) which manually implements the relations, I.e. One customer may have multiple addresses so a Customer object will have a list of addresses. This is the layer that the calcs/operations are performed on. When a change is made to one of these relational objects, the service layer deals with converting to table objects and committing updates via the repository.

a few questions:

1. What would the technical names for the layers be?
2. Are the tables representations called DTOs and the relational objects called POCOs?
3. Should the conversion from the relational objects to the table objects be done in the repository, what I call a service layer, or an in between step?
4. Lastly, does what I'm doing make sense?

Any links to applicable articles are much appreciated.

Apologies for the lack of code. Will update with examples when I'm next at a computer.

Edit: To be clear this is for windows phone & winrt for a local sqlite database. I am using a simple orm to map a table to an object, however, without emit I cannot have auto generated complex objects and as such I have had to create another layer over the simple table representations to account for this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> I have a slightly complex database layout with a few one-to-many relationships and a single many-to-many.

Ah, I have a slightly complex menu to cook. Eggs and bacon.

Ever seen a slightly complex database? let's say 200 tabbles, maybe 600 relationships? Please. A few one to many and one many to many is anything - but not complex.

> I have seen online reference entity framework to help with the ORM but unfortunately I cannot use this as I cannot 
>   use reflection/emit

Given that a slightly outdated version of entity framework is included in the .NET framework - and thus installed in the GAC and bypassing security - why exactly do you think it magically can not use reflection or emit?

Now answers:

1: None. THose aren ot layers. This all you ahve IS an ORM. I would namely call them the data access and the object management layer.

2: They are only called DTO when the are degenerate business obebjects - without logic (business, not data access). Otherwise obviously they aer not data access objects. NOw poco - do you even know what the term means? Plain Old C# Objects - i.e. not inheriting from a base class.

3: Depends.

4: no. YOur argumentation for not using reflectio / emit is weak - and that is a mild saying. You are over your head. I did maintain a commercial ORM for some time, and among all the stuff I did in my life, that likely is the most complex piece of software. There is a ton to make wrong, and you are way too fat IMHO to jump into doing that and likely will do a pretty bad case and spend a TON of time trying to solve a problem other people ahve solved - without any real gain. The dynamic sql geneation will give you white heairs, or be only able to handle very basic elements. yoour time is may better spent finding out why you can not use reflection or emitting of bytecode....

Articles.... Hm. STill my reference manual in this reagard: Scott Ambler's "Building Object Applications That Work" - I trust you are able to find it on the internet, for example at amazon.

Comment: Windows phone does not support emit. I am using a very simple orm so I do not have to generate SQL. As there is no emit, I have to manually wire up object relations.

Comment: There are some ORM's for windows phone. I Would avoid writing my own "at all costs" unless if is a project in itself.